# how to filter in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i'm trying to create a chart with d3 and i'm trying the button is clicked it filters the order by specific date and display on my chart

here's my template

```
  <div>
    <div>
      <button @click="interval = 'weekly'">Weekly</button>
      <button @click="interval = 'monthly'">Monthly</button>
    </div>
    <div ref="chart"></div>

  </div>
```

my script tag

```
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      "allOrders",
    ]),
    filteredOrders() {
      const now = new Date();
      const weekAgo = new Date(now - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      const dayAgo = new Date(now - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

      if (this.interval === "weekly") {
        return this.allOrders.filter(order => new Date(order.time) >= weekAgo);
      } else {
        return this.allOrders.filter(
          order =>
            new Date(order.time).getMonth() === now.getMonth() &&
            new Date(order.time).getFullYear() === now.getFullYear()
        );
      }
    }
  },
```

on default this displays just the monthly how do i filter the weekly and make it change on my chart

[image]

this is my watch

```
 watch: {
  interval() {
    console.log('interval changed:', this.interval);
    d3.select(this.$refs.chart)
      .select("svg")
      .remove();
    this.createPieChart();
  }
},
```

this my log

```
interval changed: weekly
```